# f#: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq, f#

I am trying to get Envelope's back from a query. Envelope is defined as follows.

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Envelope<'T> = {
    Id : Guid
    StreamId: Guid
    Created : DateTimeOffset
    Item : 'T }
```

MyLibAAS.DataStore.MyLibAASDbContext is a EF DbContext written in c#. When I extend it in f# as follows, I get the error: `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`

```
type MyLibAAS.DataStore.MyLibAASDbContext with 
    member this.GetEvents streamId = 
        query {
            for event in this.Events do
            where (event.StreamId = streamId)
            select {
                Id = event.Id;
                StreamId = streamId;
                Created = event.Timestamp;
                Item = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionnaireEvent> event.Payload)
            }
        }
```

If I return the event and map it to Envelope after the fact, it works fine.

```
type MyLibAAS.DataStore.MyLibAASDbContext with 
    member this.GetEvents streamId = 
        query {
            for event in this.Events do
            where (event.StreamId = streamId)
            select event
        } |> Seq.map (fun event ->
                {
                    Id = event.Id
                    StreamId = streamId
                    Created = event.Timestamp
                    Item = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionnaireEvent> event.Payload)
                }
            )
```

Why does this make a difference? The Envelope type is not even a EF type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**How F# records work**
F# records get compiled into .NET classes with read-only properties and a constructor that takes values of all fields as parameters (plus a few interfaces).
For example, your record would be expressed in C# roughly as follows:

```
public class Envelope<T> : IComparable<Envelope<T>>, IEquatable<Envelope<T>>, ...
{
   public Guid Id { get; private set; }
   public Guid StreamId { get; private set; }
   public DateTimeOffset Created { get; private set; }
   public T Item { get; private set; }

   public Envelope( Guid id, Guid streamId, DateTimeOffset created, T item ) {
      this.Id = id;
      this.StreamId = streamId;
      this.Created = created;
      this.Item = item;
   }

   // Plus implementations of IComparable, IEquatable, etc.
}
```

When you want to create an F# record, the F# compiler emits a call to this constructor, supplying values for all fields.
For example, the `select` part of your query would look in C# like this:

```
select new Envelope<QuestionnaireEvent>( 
   event.Id, streamId, event.Timestamp, 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionnaireEvent>(event.Payload) )
```

**Entity Framework limitations**
It so happens that Entity Framework does not allow calling non-default constructors in queries. There is a good reason: if it did allow it, you could, in principle, construct a query like this:

```
from e in ...
let env = new Envelope<E>( e.Id, ... )
where env.Id > 0
select env
```

Entity Framework wouldn't know how to compile this query, because it doesn't know that the value of `e.Id` passed to the constructor becomes the value of the property `env.Id`. This is always true for F# records, but not for other .NET classes.
Entity Framework could, in principle, recognize that `Envelope` is an F# record and apply the knowledge of the connection between constructor arguments and record properties. But it doesn't. Unfortunately, the designers of Entity Framework did not think of F# as a valid use case.
*(fun fact: C# anonymous types work the same way, and EF does make an exception for them)*

**How to fix this**
In order to make this work, you need to declare `Envelope` as a type with default constructor. The only way to do this is to make it a class, not a record:

```
type Envelope<'T>() =
   member val Id : Guid = Guid.Empty with get, set
   member val StreamId : Guid = Guid.Empty with get, set
   member val Created : DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.MinValue with get, set
   member val Item : 'T = Unchecked.defaultof<'T> with get, set
```

And then create it using property initialization syntax:

```
select Envelope<_>( Id = event.Id, StreamId = streamId, ... )
```

**Why does moving the `select` to a `Seq.map` work**
The `Seq.map` call is not part of the query expression. It does not end up as part of the `IQueryable`, so it does not end up compiled to SQL by Entity Framework. Instead, EF compiles just what's inside `query` and returns you the resulting sequence, after fetching it from SQL Server. And only after that you apply `Seq.map` to that sequence.
The code inside `Seq.map` is executed on CLR, not compiled to SQL, so it can call anything it wants, including non-default constructors.
This "fix" comes with a cost though: instead of just the fields you need, the whole `Event` entity gets fetched from DB and materialized. If this entity is heavy, this may have a performance impact.

**Another thing to watch out for**
Even if you fix the problem by making `Envelope` a type with default constructor (as suggested above), you'll still hit the next problem: the method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` can't be compiled to SQL, so Entity Framework will complain about it, too. The way you should do it is fetch all fields to the CLR side, then apply whatever non-SQL-compilable transformations you need.

Comment: "you need to declare Envelope as a type with default constructor." in your example, does it mean that this implementation lacks immutability?

Comment: Yes, it does. The way entity framework expects this type to work, it needs to create an instance, then assign values to its properties. This means that the properties must be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ to Entities, everything that happens in the `query` computational expression is actually executed within the database engine, which may reside on a remote server. Everything outside of it is executed in the running application on the client.

So, in your first snippet, Entity Framework refuses to execute `Envelope<'T>`'s constructor because, in order to do so, it would need to translate that into SQL commands for the server. This is plainly not something it can guarantee, because the constructor could potentially contain any sort of side effects and .NET framework code - it could request user input, read files from the client's hard disk, whatever.

What EF *can* do, in your second snippet, is sending its own POCO `event` objects back to the client, which is then tasked with `Seq.map`ping them to your fancy `Envelope`s, which *it* can do because it's running on your client machine with access to the full .NET framework.

Addendum: So why are *parameterless* constructors ok? What if I were to call `MsgBox()` in a parameterless constructor? I *think* that parameterless constructors work by having the *client* construct the objects (without knowing the query results), sending them to the server in serialised form, and having the server just fill the object's properties with the query results.

I haven't actually tested that. But F# record types have no parameterless constructors anyway, so the point is moot in your case.

Comment: Your theory about why parameterless constructors work is wrong.

Comment: I've read your (very thorough) answer, but it didn't quite solve that point for me. If I declare a `type Foo () = do MsgBox("foo")`, and I call that parameterless constructor inside a L2E query expression, what happens?

Comment: Depends on how that constructor is used within the query. If the constructor is used to construct values that are returned from the query (e.g. in the last `select` statement), then you get a messagebox for every returned row. If the constructor is used to create some intermediate value that isn't returned from the query, you get no messageboxes.